# sorting table row data with php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<table class="tbmed">     
 <tr> 
  <th>R1</th> 
  <th>R2</th>
  <th>R3</th>
  <th>R4</th>
 </tr>


<?php
include ("config.php");
$sql = "SELECT id, r1, r2, r3, r4  FROM table order by id DESC ";         
  
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>". 
        $row["r1"]. "</td><td>".
        $row["r2"]. "</td><td>". 
        $row["r3"]. "</td><td>". 
        $row["r4"].'  
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results"; 
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

I have some numerical data which are all positive, there may be repetitive values though.
The above code gives the results like so:

```
R1 R2 R3 R4 
10 2  5  5
4  4  1  9
....
```

I'd like to sort the output in each row of the data table, and the result would be :

```
R1 R2 R3 R4 
2  5  5  10
1  4  4  9
```

How can I achieve this ? can someone help me please?

Comment: This would be easier I think if your database structure was more highly normalised (i.e. results all stored in a separate results table, with one result per row, and a foreign key back to the ID it belongs to)

Comment: With `sort($row);` before displaying?

Comment: I can't change db. I tried sort but couldn't get it done to get the results.

Comment: @JJ Then try `natsort($row);`

Comment: `sort($row)` will reset the array keys to a zero-based index. Instead of accessing the indices `r1`, `r2` etc., you simply have to access `0`, `1` etc. now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fetch_array` instead `fetch_assoc` and apply `sort` function before output. Somehow like next:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) 
    {
        sort($row);
        echo '<td>';
        echo implode('</td><td>', $row);
        echo '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[Try code online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/cf70fd1b88100e547c2ef6f83b7e4cad/php/php81/3839059092ad0728725af7ca674f09b4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Slava. Your code works, and simpler than mine.